# How can I get email message send date & time with mailman gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailman-gem

I've made a script to get incoming messages from email account. Is there a way to get message send date time without parsing with regex `message.header`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright, it's simpy `message.date` :)